# Esperando que actualice estado en React

Tags: reactjs, async-await, async

Estoy tratando de renderizar un componente en el que busco datos y seteo un estado dentro de useEffect (bet). Luego, con ese estado establecido, necesito usarlo dentro de una función y luego establecer otro estado, pero el estado de bet aún no está disponible para usarlo. ¿Cómo ejecuto la segunda función asíncrona solo después de que se cumpla la promesa de la primera?

```
 const [bets, setBets] = useState({});
  const [table, setTable] = useState({});
useEffect(() => {
    const getBets = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/pronosticos");

        const data = await response.json();
        
        setBets(await data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
    };
getBets()

const evaluateUserResults = async ()=>{
       const data = await bets.map(..............)
        setTable(data)
}
evaluateUserResults ()
},[]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes usar `evaluateUserResults()` justo después de `getBets()` puesto que aunque ejecutas `setBets()`, este actualizará bets pero dicho cambio sólo será visible tras re-renderizar el componente, por lo que su estado dentro del useEffect sigue siendo `[]`. Puedes crear dos `useEffect` en vez de uno, de forma que al renderizarse por primera vez el componente, se haga la petición de datos para setear bets. Tras setear bets, se ejecuta otro `useEffect` que hace los cálculos correspondientes con el valor de bets actualizado

```js
const [bets, setBets] = useState({});
const [table, setTable] = useState({});
  
  const getBets = async () => {

    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/pronosticos");
       
    const data = await response.json();
        
    setBets(data);
  };
  
  const evaluateUserResults = () => {
    const data = bets.map(..............)
    setTable(data)
  }
  
useEffect( () => {
  getBets()
})
  
useEffect(() => {
  if (bets.TieneXPropiedad){
    //Luego de que se renderize el componente la primera vez, si bets tiene x propiedad que comprueba que existe, entonces haz algo
    evaluateUserResults()
  }
},[bets]}
```